# Responsive Bootstrap columns

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been playing around with Bootstrap an its responsive grid layout for a while and was wondering if something I had in mind was possible using bootstrap. I want to create a grid layout that will adapt from 3 columns on a large screen to 2 columns and a third under the 2 on a medium sized screen and then finally all 3 columns under each other on a small screen.

If anyone has any advice or something I can refer to that would be great.

This is what i have been playing around with but for some reason i cant get it to work how i want. 
On a large screen the columns appear:

```
|1|3|2|
```

What I want:

```
|1|2|3|
```

On a medium it is:

```
|1|2|
|3|
```

What I want:

```
|1|2|
| 3 |


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="background-color:black">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-lg-push-3" style="background-color:blue">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-3" style="background-color:red">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, surely it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Woah, "advice" is quite a forbidden word. It attracts downvotes and close votes if you don't provide code.

Comment: Bootstrap Grid system already does that, choose the right class for the grid in different browser-width (viewport)

Comment: @Roope Please check the edit I have made.

Comment: I made some edit to the answer after your edited question. The second row is centered now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inbuilt Bootstrap grid classes. Since it is a 12 column grid system, use the following:

**`col-lg-4`**

Divide into 3 on larger screens

**`col-md-6`**

Divide into 2 on medium sized screens, one down under

**`col-xs-12`**

Expand to 100% on extra small and small devices.

In order to center the second row on medium sized screens, use **`col-md-push-3`** Reset the margin on larger screen by using **`col-lg-push-0`**

To span the full width of the second row, use **`col-md-12`**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Basic panel example
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Basic panel example
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Basic panel example
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I dont want the panel in the centre, Im trying to have it span the entire width under the two columns above

Comment: @Mehul You should be able to see how that works already, it's very simple. There's 12 columns, just change the numbers the way you want them.

Comment: @Manoj Make that last column `col-md-12`.

Comment: Thanks Roope! :) @Mehul I suggest you create a question of completed version. It is hard to determine what you are looking for, had to make 3 different versions of the answer. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Bootstrap has various screen size related class.
You can use

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-3"> 
   ....................
   ....................
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set your classes up wrong.

> On a large screen the columns appear:

```
1 | 3 | 2
```

This is because you're using `col-lg-pull-3` and `col-lg-push-3`. Removing those classes will get you the results you want on large screens. You're using `col-lg-3`. 3 x 3 = 9. You should use `col-lg-4`, since 3 x 4 = 12.

```
1 | 2 | 3
```

> On a medium it is, What I want:

```
  | 1 | 2 |
  |   3   |
```

Set the following class to your third div. `col-md-12`, and use `col-md-6` for your first two `<div`s.

From Bootstrap: *Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases.*

*Mobile first*, so it's best practice to set your classes in your markup in this order: `col-xs-*` > `col-sm-*` > `col-md-*` > `col-lg-*`

Your markup should look like this:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color:black">1</div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color:blue">2</div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4" style="background-color:red">3</div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle demo for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/zn4L3wcc/1/.